# How should I work with checkbox in laravel?

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-5.3

In my `create.blade.php` I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-check">
        <label for="active">active</label>
        <input id="active" name = "active" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="1">
    </div>
```

And in my `edit.blade.php` the following:

```
<div class="form-check">
            <label for="active">active</label>
            <input id="active" name = "active" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="{!!$company->
            active!!}"> 
        </div>
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec04c5/1) of my db structure with data.

1. When submitting either with the checkbox checked they work fine
2. When editing a record with active set to 1, the checkbox isn't checked when opening the form

I know there's no value when not checked and when opening the checkbox isn't 'on' because the value is 1 instead of 'on'.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually an HTML problem, you are just using the input the wrong way, you have to use the `checked` instead of `value`:

```
<input 
   id="active" 
   name="active" 
   type="checkbox" 
   class="form-check-input" 
   checked="{{ $company->active ? 'checked' : '' }}"
>
```

Comment: Already +1 for the first problem, displaying the checked box when editing. How should it be changed, so I can send unchecked values?

Comment: What do you mean by unchecked values? You just have to keep name="active"  to receive its current state in Laravel. If it's not checked, Laravel will send you nothing. So Input::get('active') will be NULL.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio, I had to change the database to except `null` values. Is there any other way? i.e.: unchecked gets value 0 instead of being `null`

Comment: there's still something wrong, with records that have value `null`  the checkbox is also checked.

Comment: You can do something like ´$request->merge(['active' => Input::get('active') ? 1 : 0]);´

Comment: Look we cannot know what values you have on your database if you don't show us more code or your database. Depending on the value of ´$company->active´ the checkbox will be checked or unchecked. To be unchecked it must be ´NULL´, ´false´ or ´0´, otherwise it will be checked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131203/discussion-between-davejal-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro).

Comment: added my db structure with sample data